# WebRTC: Add rooms to simple WebRTC & WebSocket app - Advice Needed

Tags: android, node.js, websocket, webrtc, wwsapi

I am very new to `webrtc` and coding, so apologies if this is not a clear question.

I have followed the Shane Tully example [here](https://shanetully.com/2014/09/a-dead-simple-webrtc-example/) and amended it to run on my AWS server. Its running find but it only allows me one connection at a time. I would like to have users enter my URL followed by a room name in order to connect to a room.

e.g. www.myurl.com/apple where apple is the room that will be created. Here is an example - if you add /apppl at the end of this URL it will create a room. (The code for this example is rather complex and uses `socket.io`. where I use ws for Node to create the websockets)

Does anyone have any advice on this? My overall aim is to create an Android App which incorporates video calling functionality, and uses WebView to display the calling feature, which is why I need different URLs for each pair of devices so they both access the same room.

Thank you in advance!
Claire

**Server Code:**

```
const HTTPS_PORT = 443;
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const WebSocketServer = WebSocket.Server;

const serverConfig = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Create a server for the client html page
var handleRequest = function(request, response) {
    // Render the single client html file for any request the HTTP server receives
    console.log('request received: ' + request.url);

    if(request.url === '/') {
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.end(fs.readFileSync('client/index.html'));

    } else if(request.url === '/webrtc.js') {
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'});
        response.end(fs.readFileSync('client/webrtc.js'));
    }
};

var httpsServer = https.createServer(serverConfig, handleRequest);
httpsServer.listen(HTTPS_PORT, '0.0.0.0');

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Create a server for handling websocket calls
var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: httpsServer});

wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function(message) {
        // Broadcast any received message to all clients
        console.log('received: %s', message);
        wss.broadcast(message);
    });
});

wss.broadcast = function(data) {
    this.clients.forEach(function(client) {
        if(client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
            client.send(data);
        }
    });
};

console.log('Server running. Visit https://localhost:' + HTTPS_PORT + ' in Firefox/Chrome (note the HTTPS; there is no HTTP -> HTTPS redirect!)');
//console.log("TEST TEST TEST" + JSON.stringify(room));
```

**Client Code:**

```
var localVideo;
var remoteVideo;
var peerConnection;
var uuid;
var constraints = {
        video: true,
        audio: true,
    };

var peerConnectionConfig = {
    'iceServers': [
        {'urls': 'stun:stun.services.mozilla.com'},
        {'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'},
    ]
};

function pageReady() {
    uuid = uuid(); 

    localVideo = document.getElementById('localVideo');
    remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');
    serverConnection = new WebSocket('wss://' + window.location.hostname + ':443');
    serverConnection.onmessage = gotMessageFromServer;

    if(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(getUserMediaSuccess).catch(errorHandler);

    } else {
        alert('Your browser does not support getUserMedia API');
    }
}

//CB if it is possible to run gerUserMedia then gets the local video stream
function getUserMediaSuccess(stream) {
    localStream = stream;
    localVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream); //Depreciated
    //localVideo.srcObject = stream;
}


//CB this function starts the call 
function start(isCaller) {
    peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnectionConfig);
    peerConnection.onicecandidate = gotIceCandidate;
    peerConnection.onaddstream = gotRemoteStream;
    //peerConnection.ontrack = gotRemoteStream;
    peerConnection.addStream(localStream);

    if(isCaller) {
        peerConnection.createOffer().then(createdDescription).catch(errorHandler);
    }
}

function gotMessageFromServer(message) {
    if(!peerConnection) start(false);

    var signal = JSON.parse(message.data);

    // Ignore messages from ourself
    if(signal.uuid == uuid) return;

    if(signal.sdp) {
        peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(signal.sdp)).then(function() {
            // Only create answers in response to offers
            if(signal.sdp.type == 'offer') {
                peerConnection.createAnswer().then(createdDescription).catch(errorHandler);
            }
        }).catch(errorHandler);
    } else if(signal.ice) {
        peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(signal.ice)).catch(errorHandler);
    }
}

function gotIceCandidate(event) {
    if(event.candidate != null) {
        serverConnection.send(JSON.stringify({'ice': event.candidate, 'uuid': uuid}));
    }
}

function createdDescription(description) {
    console.log('got description');

    peerConnection.setLocalDescription(description).then(function() {
        serverConnection.send(JSON.stringify({'sdp': peerConnection.localDescription, 'uuid': uuid}));
    }).catch(errorHandler);
}

function gotRemoteStream(event) {
    console.log('got remote stream');
    remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream); 
    //remoteVideo.src = event.stream;
}

function errorHandler(error) {
    console.log(error);
}

// Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/105074/515584
// Strictly speaking, it's not a real UUID, but it gets the job done here
function uuid() {
  function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1);
  }

  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}
```

Comment: WebRCT is so complicated. First you need to understand architecture totally. I can't answer your question now but I have already implemented too long ago using this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575368/webrtc-flow-of-function-calls-for-making-calls-android

Comment: Great, I'll take a look at that! Yeah, it is complex, I'm a student and was asked to do a project to create a video link between two Android tablets, it looked like WebRTC was going to be easy as that's what it said EVERYWHERE!!! Its not, but StackOverflow is great for help!

Comment: This question appears to be about [discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29056385/918910), which is actually outside the scope of WebRTC. If that's complicated, it's not WebRTC's fault.

Comment: You are right!! I think it's just that I don't have enough basic knowledge so I am finding WebRTC hard, but I think its because I am lumping it together into everything that goes into creating the video link!! I take it back!! Thanks for the link, I will look into it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the server's code in the example. Right now it is just broadcasting all the messages to all other clients. What you need to do is right a logic at server side to send messages to only those clients with same room id.

[I have written a webRTC based p2p scalable broadcast following Shane Tully's example. Click here to see](https://github.com/akshat7101999/WebRTC-scalable-broadcast-p2p)

You can follow from here and get an idea on what i mean by sending signalling messages to specific clients only. In your case message broadcasting should occur only for those clients having the same room id. I hope this helps !!